# Bootstrap Navbar display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boostrap Navbar **width** is dependent on it's **content** and on the **screen size**.

For small screen sizes, navbar titles are packed in a single button and for large screen sizes, if there is sufficient space, the titles are all well aligned.

For intermediate screen sizes, the result can be very anaesthetic like shown on the picture below:

[image]

Does it give a way to have either a single drop-down button or all title aligned if sufficient space but to prevent from having a configuration with navabar content on top of one-another?

Here is a Fiddle with the example above:https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/165/

And the corresponding code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">website</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> a long Title2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="themes">a long Title3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
            <li><a href="#"> Item1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title4</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title5</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title6</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title7</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">a long Title8</li>
            


          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the navbar values for the default breakpoint so that the bar itself is hidden and the hamburger button stays visible until the screen width is larger.  Use something like:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

The `991px` value for the media query `max-width` is the custom breakpoint value you can change.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/167/)

Comment: Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own mobile menu breakpoint.
You can do it by customizing your Bootstrap version. The simplest way is by going to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system and define @grid-float-breakpoint (for example, 800px). So you will be able then to download a Bootstrap files with changed breakpoint.

Comment: Thx, I dident knew this possibility to customize the boostrap version on this page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a lot unclosed `a` tags, starting with *Title4*. Next step, to overwrite `@media-query` for navbar, Lloyd Banks have written really good solution for this case. You may include it in your `styles.css` file, linked below `bootstrap.css` file. I updated your *jsfiddle* with closed tags and new breakpoint

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/bb61c412/168/)